# Sharing a shiny application with the members of my workspace in databricks

Tags: r, shiny, databricks

I recently started using RStudio Server through Databricks.

In order to launch RStudio Server each member of our workspace (10 members) needs to log in with their own credentials (I think that this is how Databricks is set up and potentially the cause of our issue).

Is it possible to share a shiny application that I created, only with the members of my workspace?
Is it possible for other members of my workspace to see my code? Something similar when one shares a python notebook through databricks. I do not want to push my application to shinyapps.io

I tried sharing the URL of my shiny application with one of my colleagues, but she got a message: "connection refused".

Would the solution be to install shiny server in databricks (if that is even feasible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today on Databricks you cannot reliably share a URL to a Shiny app with your teammates.  Product and Engineering are planning on releasing a feature in Q4 2020 to support hosting Shiny apps in Databricks Notebooks.  You could then share the URL to the notebook and interact with the app.

Until then, you have two choices.

1. Share the Shiny App files with your team, either through version control or by persisting them in a common location such as `/dbfs/` on Databricks.  Then they can launch the apps from inside a hosted RStudio session on Databricks.  If you leverage DBFS you can have a shared folder where you put all your Shiny apps, and you can [browse DBFS](https://github.com/marygracemoesta/R-User-Guide/blob/master/Developing_on_Databricks/RStudio_integrations.md#persisting-work) from the RStudio File Viewer.
2. [Install Shiny Server](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#getting-started) on a VM in the cloud (AWS/Azure/GCP), move the Shiny app files and data to that server, then share the URL with your teammates.  Depending on your security requirements you may want to check with your security and cloud architects prior to publishing the app this way.  There's a really nice guide on how to do this on [this blog](https://canovasjm.netlify.app/2020/01/08/deploy-you-own-shiny-server-on-azure/#enable-port-3838).

Comment: Thay was helpful, if I install shiny server in an Azure VM, is there a way to have the shiny application to read the data that is stored in /dbfs/ ?

Comment: If you have the data in Delta Lake or Parquet, you can use ODBC to read the data.  We did a talk on it at SAIS 2020: https://databricks.com/session_na20/how-r-developers-can-build-and-share-data-and-ai-applications-that-scale-with-databricks-and-rstudio-connect

Comment: Reading files directly from cloud storage is possible, you'd just need to set up the authentication to the bucket/blob using a package like aws.s3 or AzureStoR